# habtm relationship does not support :dependent option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

Is it true that HABTM relationships do not support the `:dependent` option?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I am trying rails edge.

Comment: As an exercise, I recommend reading this API part titled `Deleting from associations`, specially in the part `What gets deleted?`. That made me understand why and what's happening behind
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yep, It doesn't support it. [See the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many). Generally `habtm` is meant only for very very simple cases and if you start needing more complex things you should switch to `has_many :through`.

Answer (score 87):

If you want to keep to the simple `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, you could add this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  before_destroy { posts.clear }
end
```

Which will clear the join table of all entries of that `person`. Note: This only removes records from the join table, it does not destroy the `posts` (which makes sense if it is a bi-direction `has_and_belongs_to_many` because the `post` might be referenced by other `persons`).

But guessing from your names (`Person` and `Post`) I would assume that you can probably get away with a `Person has_many :posts` and a `Post belongs_to :person` in which case you can use the `:dependent => :destroy` on the `has_many` association.

Comment: Could you please add how you would implement a `dependent: :destroy` action on a **bi-directional** `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship which links to the **same model**?

Comment: I'm not sure if the syntax was ever originally like this answer, but I know in rails 4 it is supposed to be `before_destroy { posts.clear }`

Comment: also you could use this to get the whole destroy effect `after_destroy do
    User.find(:all, :uniq => true, :joins => :posts,
              :conditions => 'posts.id is NULL').each(&:destroy)
  end` but might as well use has_many through at that point.

Comment: I found that i don't need to do `before_destroy { posts.clear }` in rails 4.2.0 (postgresql). Rails deletes relationship by default (it doesn't delete related record, post in this example).

Comment: Nice tip Faith.  has_and_belongs_to_many continues to delete the associations in rails 5.0.0beta2

Comment: @Fatih comment need to be an answer!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
  before_destroy do
    posts.each { |post| post.destroy }
  end
end
```

You don't need to posts.clear as Rails 4.2+ handles this already.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Rails 4.2+ and 5+ both will destroy association table as soon as you destroy the HABTM association.