# Prevent destruction if HABTM relation isnt empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
    class Annex
      has_and_belongs_to_many: :documents
    end

    class Document
      has_and_belongs_to_many: :annexes
    end
```

I want to implement this behavior: if the annex is associated to at least one document, it shouldn't be destroyed.

Is there a easy rails way of doing this or will I have to make a work around this?

Will I have to use a before_destroy method or something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799746/habtm-relationship-does-not-support-dependent-option

Comment: Actually what I want to do is the opposite of that question, he wants to destroy I want to prevent destruction

Comment: In that case; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
class Annex < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
  before_destroy { raise "Can't destroy Annex, because it's still associated to 1 or more documents" if documents.any? }
end
```

Comment: I see, so rails can't handle it with a relation option after all. But this seems dry enough, thanks.