# Rails select by number of associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following models in my rails app:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles, dependent: :destroy

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, dependent: :destroy

class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, touch: true
```

I need to extract all Students who has less than articles and I need to extract all Students who's last ticket title is 'Something'.

Everything I tried so far takes a lot of time. I tried mapping and looping through all Students. But I guess what I need is a joined request. I am looking for the most efficient way to do it, as database I am working with is quite large.

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: do you really need a dependent: :destroy for students association in article which cause deletion of student record on deletion of corresponding article.

Comment: @DileepNandanam As far as I understand, only record of joined table is deleted not the records themselves.

Comment: @TuesdayFourAM it soesn't do either of them for HABTM associations, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799746/habtm-relationship-does-not-support-dependent-option

Answer (score 2):

You asked
`"I need to extract all Students who has less than articles"`.  I'll presume you meant `"I need to extract all Students who have less than X articles"`. In that case, you want `group` and `having` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group.

For example, `Article.group(:student_id).having('count(articles.id) > X').pluck(:student_id)`.

To address your second question, you can use eager loading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations to speed up your code.

```
result = students.filter do |student|
  students.tickets.last.name == 'Something'
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting error though

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "articles.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" GROUP BY "articles"."stu...
               ^
: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" GROUP BY "articles"."student_id" HAVING (count(articles.id) < '5')):

Comment: Than you for the hint regarding the eager loading - it worked out for me:

studs.each do |client|
          t = client.tickets.last
          if t && pt.include?(t.pt)
            ticket_res << client
            puts "Client with payment: #{client.name}, #{client.id}, #{client.tickets.last.pt}"
          end
        end

Comment: Ah, I edited the answer and added the `.pluck(:student_id)` to address Postgres's complaints. This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418504/pgerror-in-group-by-clause post explains why you need it

Answer (score 2):

go with @MCI's answer for your first question. But a filter/select/find_all or whatever (although I havn't heared about filter method in ruby) through students record takes n queries where n is the number of student records (called an n+1 query).

```
studs = Student.find_by_sql(%{select tmp.id from (
  select student_id as id from tickets where name='Something' order by tickets.created_at desc
) tmp group by tmp.id})
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem is I need to select only if the last record has that name, not any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here association is HABTM so below query should work

```
x = 10
Student.joins(:articles).group("articles_students.student_id").having("count(articles.id) < ?",x)
```