# Rails - Add relationship automatically on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I have two models:

```
class RecordProduct < ApplicationRecord
end

class ShopiTagProduct < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And I want to create a many to many relationship between models. I execute this command:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts record_products:references:index shopi_tag_products:references:index
```

This command create this migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        create_join_table :record_products, :shopi_tag_products do |t|
            t.references :record_products, foreign_key: true, index: {name: :productId}
            t.references :shopi_tag_products, foreign_key: true, index: {name: :tagId}
        end
    end
end
```

when execute rake db:migrate throws an error: 'name_index_tooooo_long' on table 'name_new_table' is too long; the limit is 64 characters.

So, I change the migration class to:

```
class CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        create_join_table :record_products, :shopi_tag_products do |t|
            t.references :record_products, foreign_key: true, index: {name: :productId}
            t.references :shopi_tag_products, foreign_key: true, index: {name: :tagId}
        end
    end
end
```

When I execute rake db:migrate it create the table, but with columns are repetead:

```
record_product_id
shopi_tag_product_id
record_products_id
shopi_tag_products_id
```

I have two question.

First: Whay the columns are repetead? What is the correct way for columns to be generated properly?

Second: Should I manually add the relations (has_and_belongs_to_many) in the models or are these added automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's possible to add `has_many` into models automatically in your case, I add it manually by hand in such cases.

Running `rails g migration CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts record_products:references:index shopi_tag_products:references:index`
 would generate this migrations:

```rb
class CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :record_products, :shopi_tag_products do |t|
      t.references :record_products, foreign_key: true
      t.references :shopi_tag_products, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

`t.references` are redundant here, since you already use `create_join_table`

`rails g migration CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts record_products shopi_tag_products` will do the job.
It will generate such file:

```rb
class CreateJoinTableRecordProductsShopyTagProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_join_table :record_products, :shopi_tag_products do |t|
      # t.index [:record_product_id, :shopi_tag_product_id]
      # t.index [:shopi_tag_product_id, :record_product_id]
    end
  end
end
```

You need to uncomment indexes and assing names to them to solve problem with long index names.

As an alternative you can go this way:
`rails g model record_products_shopi_tag_products record_product:references shopi_tag_product:references`
It will generate:

```rb
class CreateRecordProductsShopiTagProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :record_products_shopi_tag_products do |t|
      t.references :record_product, foreign_key: true
      t.references :shopi_tag_product, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Note that here `create_table` is used instead of `create_join_table`, so in this case you have to write `t.references`.
In this migration you have to add `, index: {name: ...}` to solve problem with long indexes.

I have written such models:
`rails g model RecordProduct name:string`
`rails g model ShopiTagProduct name:string`

record_product.rb

```rb
class RecordProduct < ApplicationRecord
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :shopi_tag_products

  # not needed if you use has_and_belongs_to_many
  has_many :record_products_shopi_tag_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shopi_tag_products, through: :record_products_shopi_tag_products

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

shopi_tag_product.rb

```rb
class ShopiTagProduct < ApplicationRecord
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :record_products

  # not needed if you use has_and_belongs_to_many
  has_many :record_products_shopi_tag_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :record_products, through: :record_products_shopi_tag_products

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

record_products_shopi_tag_product.rb (not needed if you use has_and_belongs_to_many)

```rb
class RecordProductsShopiTagProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :record_product
  belongs_to :shopi_tag_product
end
```

seeds.rb

```rb
RecordProduct.destroy_all
ShopiTagProduct.destroy_all

r = RecordProduct.create!(name: 'foo')
s = ShopiTagProduct.create!(name: 'bar')

r.shopi_tag_products << s
r.save!

p ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('select * from record_products_shopi_tag_products')
```

```
$ rake db:seed
[{"record_product_id"=>4, "shopi_tag_product_id"=>4}]
```

I would strongly suggest to use `has_many through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` because `has_and_belongs_to_many` doesn't support `dependent: destroy`
([habtm relationship does not support :dependent option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799746/habtm-relationship-does-not-support-dependent-option))